# CSS Border wont appear

Tags: css, border

My CSS border won't appear on all the browsers I have tried (firefox, safari, chrome)

```
#content_right {
background-color: #FFF;
float: right;
height: 150px;
width: 400px;
margin-right: 20px;
border: 2px solid ##F89B29;


<div id="content_right">
  <div id="phone"><img src="images/phone.jpg" width="60" height="60" alt="Phone" /></div>
  <div id="phonenumber"><h1>8342 4526</h1></div>
  <div id="phonequote">free non obligation quote</div>
</div>
```

I'm thinking it might be another element on my page. I am using dreamweaver, and on the design view my border is visible.

Any clues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a second # in front of the color specification for the border. You should get rid of that one.

Comment: Its amazing how many times something doesn't work because you miss one character. Thanks mate, that was the issue!

Comment: You might want to consider using a linter. In many cases, a such can resolve such problems. http://csslint.net/ would be an option but for better usability you should look for plugins for your editor of choice.